# Finding parameter estimate differences with unevenly matched datasets in SAS

Tags: merge, sas

I'm using SAS, and I need to find the difference between observed and model data parameter estimates. My problem is that the two datasets can't be matched up one-to-one. Here's a shortened example of what I'm working with:

```
data models; input subject $ model $ _RMSE_ intercept X1 X2 _RSQ_;
datalines;
A   X   0.065140589 -0.047688351    0.000607126 -7.07E-07   0.205605571
A   Y   0.124751538 -0.054223164    0.001032068 -4.20E-07   0.372413362
A   Z   0.085574381 -0.044588016    0.000816996 -9.10E-07   0.178236114
B   X   0.263592542 -0.172935382    0.003415054 -4.69E-06   0.204917524
B   Y   0.412902318 -0.060747534    0.002600555 -1.06E-06   0.255847395
B   Z   0.413126643 -0.200871559    0.003991876 -3.93E-06   0.216041967
;
run;

data obs; input subject $ set $ _RMSE_ intercept X1 X2 _RSQ_;
datalines;
A   1   0.119549577 0.033531462 0.000274086 1.60E-07    0.218312257
A   2   0.115862664 0.032904509 0.00024085  2.19E-07    0.235676326
A   3   0.104894694 0.027893524 0.000203312 3.04E-07    0.293416317
A   4   0.097880177 0.002515158 0.000250778 3.03E-07    0.373180007
A   5   0.077454025 -0.002850176    0.000230676 4.11E-07    0.477068396
B   1   0.130485919 0.089148147 0.00048157  -3.01E-07   0.131315385
B   2   0.124873502 0.07543287  0.000413505 -1.31E-07   0.170287809
B   3   0.107846946 0.040220511 0.000470348 -1.17E-07   0.282334021
B   4   0.113946123 0.074896237 0.000182358 2.69E-07    0.21846564
B   5   0.109164001 0.046820011 0.000441038 -4.49E-08   0.240814334
;
run;
```

I need to find the difference between each subject-model parameter estimate and all observation parameter estimates for that subject. So, the first few lines of the output would look something like this:

```
SUBJECT MODEL   SET _RMSE_  Intercept   X1  X2  _RSQ_
A   X   1   -0.054408988    -0.081219813    0.00033304  -8.67E-07   -0.012706686
A   X   2   -0.050722075    -0.08059286 0.000366276 -9.26E-07   -0.030070755
A   X   3   -0.039754105    -0.075581875    0.000403814 -1.01E-06   -0.087810746
A   X   4   -0.032739587    -0.050203509    0.000356348 -1.01E-06   -0.167574436
A   X   5   -0.012313436    -0.044838175    0.00037645  -1.12E-06   -0.271462824
A   Y   1   0.00520196  -0.087754626    0.000757982 -5.80E-07   0.154101105
A   Y   2   0.008888873 -0.087127673    0.000791218 -6.39E-07   0.136737036
A   Y   3   0.019856844 -0.082116688    0.000828755 -7.24E-07   0.078997045
A   Y   4   0.026871361 -0.056738322    0.000781289 -7.24E-07   -0.000766645
A   Y   5   0.047297512 -0.051372988    0.000801391 -8.31E-07   -0.104655034
```

If the sets were even, I would just merge them and find the difference between the variables. But with the uneven sets, I'm really not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a many-to-many merge: each row for model A in the `models` dataset should be matched up with each row for model A in the `obs` dataset. The easiest way to do it in SAS is PROC SQL:

```
PROC SQL noprint;
CREATE TABLE merged as
SELECT models._RMSE_ as RMSE1, obs._RMSE_ as RMSE2,
       models.Intercept as Intercept1, obs.Intercept as Intercept2
FROM models JOIN obs
ON models.Model = obs.Model;
```

Then you can calculate the differences in a data step (you would need to rename all variables, not just `_RMSE_` and `Intercept`, of course). If you look into SQL, there is a way to create calculated variables on the fly, but this might be easier to understand the first time around.